# Why does Keys folder not show all Keys from the Columns folder?

Tags: sql-server

I"m using *MS SQL Server Management Studio* v18.10
The CandidateID column is a [Foreign] Key, but does not show up in the Keys folder.

[image]

[image]

EDIT:  That key is also not in the Constraints folder

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you don't see it, it doesn't mean that it's not there. I would wager based on the name that it is the `FK_CandidateDetail_Candidates` key.

You can confirm this by right-clicking on your table -> Script Table as -> CREATE To -> New Query Editor Window (or Clipboard and paste it into a text editor, your choice). You should be able to find a line like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CandidateDetail] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [some_key_name] FOREIGN KEY([CandidateID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[SomeOtherTable] ([SomeColumn])
```

Or if you prefer queries:

```
SELECT  c.name AS ColumnName,
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.constraint_object_id) AS ConstraintName,
        OBJECT_NAME(fkc.referenced_object_id) AS RefTableName,
        rc.name AS RefColumnName
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.columns c
    ON c.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
    AND c.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns rc
    ON rc.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
    AND rc.column_id = fkc.referenced_column_id
WHERE fkc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.CandidateDetail')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the column name to be shown, rename the constraint to include it in the constraint name.

Whoever created the other constraints chose to include the column(s) used in the constraint names.

Comment: The Key that's missing from Keys (but present in Columns) is not in Constraints